# Heroku deployed but not update

Tags: laravel, git, vue.js, heroku, deployment

My app is Laravel mix, I have updated my code and deploy to heroku with the command `git add .`, `git commit -m "fixed title"` and `git push heroku master`, but my web app is still the old version.
I have checked my local branch with `heroku releases`, both are the same.
I also create a new branch and push with `git push heroku my_new_branch:master` and the problem is still occurring.

Comment: Honestly, it is much easier to create a repository on a `GitHub` account and link it to `Heroku`, also adds automatic deploys when the origin is pushed.

Comment: Also, please give more info on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to deploy my updates, it's completely deployed but the website doesn't change. @hexerous

Comment: Have you tried turning on maintenance mode (and turning back on) or creating a new app? This has also happened to me, using GitHub worked.

Comment: Try opening a command prompt (normal user) and type in `where heroku`. Tell me what you get.

Comment: @hexerous this is the output from -> `where heroku`: /usr/local/bin/heroku. I have tried turning on/off maintenance mode but still has the problem. my website not update